# Is it legal to live on commercial property?

Tags: canada, real-estate, property, municipal-bylaws, residency

I live in Grande Prairie, Alberta, and I noticed that some commercial properties in town are very affordable. I don't plan on starting a business nor do I plan on trying within this year.

I did try researching my city's bylaws, but all I could find was the purposes that I could use my property for based on zoning, none of which were relevant to personal use.

Is it legal to live on commercial property?
And as a partially overlapping question, it legal to own the property without using it for commercial purposes?

Comment: I don't _know_ for certain, thus a comment, rather than an answer. The property may need to be zoned commercial/residential. It may need to have a full kitchen and bath. Any bedroom may need an exterior window, etc. Property taxes may be higher for commercial property.

Comment: This would depend upon the exact language of the zoning ordinance in question.

Answer (score 2):

The way you describe it makes it sound like sort of neighborhood in transition-meaning the businesses have either closed or left and there's still a few stragglers. I would talk to a realtor in that area and simply ask, that is probably the quickest way to find out.

I did it with one of my commercial properties once. The city was surprised to find me there after they filed an eminent domain action on the property.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be legal. You would have to rent a commercial property, and then make it a motel. Then you can make it residential for you, by not letting anyone else use the motel.

Comment: Do you know of any actual precedent case where courts / local administrations accepted this arrangement? Or is it just some legal loophole you think you discovered?

Comment: @Philipp that's a good question.  Furthermore, there are of course regulatory requirements implicit in "then make it a motel," so it's probably not as easy as it sounds.  Jarri: one might also consider keeping the motel nominally open to the public but charging outrageously high rates. If someone *does* book, it would at least be worthwhile to accommodate them.